# How do I print out an unsigned int in binary in C++?

Tags: c++, binary, type-conversion

I am trying to print out an unsigned value in binary in C++. I have found many hacks for this task such as

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0040__Data-Types/Printinganunsignedintegerinbits.htm

However, I feel that there should be a much more straightforward way, perhaps with `sprintf`. After all, there are very straightforward ways to print a value in hex or octal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple - Use STL [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/):

e.g.

```
bitset<10> n (120ul); // 10 bits in this case
cout << n.to_string() << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

printf familiy does not support base-2 printing. You need to use a custom or non-standard function, such as [itoa](https://code.google.com/p/my-itoa/) (just set the base/radix to 2).

Comment: Indeed, there is no way to write a base two printf/cout without resorting to bit masking and shifting. Although you can resort to other magic, or look around for libraries that do support it.